# Funcion del This

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

Mi problema esta en que no se exactamente lo que hace this en realidad y ahora tengo un objecto que dentro tiene varios tipos de datos y uno de esos son un objecto y un array function y lo que usaba el this era para llamar los atributos ya definidas en el objecto mi codigo es:

```
const joa = {
    nombre: "Joaquin",
    apellido: "Contreras",
    edad: 19,
    pasatiempo: ["Artes Marciales","Fuerza","Programacion"],
    soltero: false,
    conctato:{
        email: "joakingcontreras2@gmail.com",
        tel: "3546437025",
    },
    saludar: () =>{
        console.log("Hola");
    },
    decirMiNombre: () =>{
        console.log(`Hola me llamo ${this.nombre} ${this.apellido} mi edad es ${this.conctato.email}.`);
    }
}
```

Esto lo siguo del curso de JonMircha. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

La funcionalidad que tiene `this` en el contexto de la `function` **decirMiNombre( )** es de acceder a las propiedades del `object` ya que no se encuentran declaradas dentro del `scope` del mismo.

Segun [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#The_bind_method):

> In most cases, the value of this is determined by how a function is called (runtime binding). It can't be set by assignment during execution, and it may be different each time the function is called. ES5 introduced the bind() method to set the value of a function's this regardless of how it's called, and ES2015 introduced arrow functions which don't provide their own this binding (it retains the this value of the enclosing lexical context).

Es por eso que no es lo mismo usar una `arrow function` que una `function`, ya que no se obtiene de forma directa `this` como se ve en el ejemplo de la `function` **saludar( )**.

```js
const joa = {
  nombre: 'Joaquin',
  apellido: 'Contreras',
  edad: 19,
  pasatiempo: ['Artes Marciales', 'Fuerza', 'Programacion'],
  soltero: false,
  conctato: {
    email: 'joakingcontreras2@gmail.com',
    tel: '3546437025',
  },
  saludar: () => {
    console.log(this.nombre);
  },
  decirMiNombre: function() {
    console.log(`Hola me llamo ${this.apellido} ${this.apellido} mi edad es ${this.conctato.email}.`);
  },
};

joa.saludar();
joa.decirMiNombre();
```